# .NET application versions and preserving calculated values

Tags: .net, database, version

I have been wondering what would be the best way to solve the following situation:

The application is version 1.0.0 and contains an object that perform a calculation, let' say

```
TheResult = SomeInputValue * 2
```

*(lets assume SomeInputValue=100, so TheResult=200)*

SomeInputValue is stored in the database but TheResult is not.

Then, we update the application to version 1.0.1 because we notify that we had a bug in the calculation formula forTheResult and correct it to the 1.0.1 version:

```
TheResult = SomeInputValue ^ * 2.5
```

*(TheResult=250)*

Now, when the user gets his 1.0.1 version he notifies that TheResult is not anymore the same as earlier. But this is not acceptable in our situation. We want the user to see 200, no matter if that came with a buggy calculation at a time. But we also want to be able to give option for the user to get the value calculated in line with 1.0.1 as well.

I have not found any other way so far than to save also TheResult to the database and insert the version number to the same row as additional information. Then when the database item is read with 1.0.1 we are not calculating it but instead showing the database value 200 and notify the user that this value came from database and it might be different if recalculated with the new version.

**Is this the way to maintain calculated values with earlier application versions** (by inserting a version number information to the database) ?

Comment: If what you created is satisfactory then this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is to extend the table with a new column that contains the output of the calculated value. Because the column value will be null immediately after altering the table, you can then apply an UPDATE statement to store the calculated value using your version 1 calculation method. From then on, in your application, store the calculated value using the new calculation method.

The UPDATE statement would be something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET NewStoredValueColumn = SomeInputValueColumn * 2;
```

This would have to be done during the upgrade. If your installer doesn't automatically run SQL statements to make changes to the database, add this to the file that the user must run as a part of the upgrade.

***DO NOT*** take the shortcut of trying to upgrade the database from your application on the first run. If you have even the slightest possibility of having multiple users running the application at the same time, you run the risk of having the new stored value column added multiple times.